# paypal _cart ipn

Tags: paypal, cart, paypal-ipn

I have a problem with ipn listener, it works both from the "Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator" that from the form on my site with cmd x_click.
the problem is when I try to edit "_xclick" in  "_cart" to make payments with multiple items.
paypal makes the transition, but ipn no give signs of life...

anyone have any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: What does your "_xclick" in "_cart" look like? I'm not sure the x-click supports multi-item purchases...

Comment: if i try single items and x-click it works, but when I change the form by placing multiple items and cmd _cart not receive any response from paypal...

Comment: Check the documentation to make sure Paypal allows multiple items in the x-click's cart (I don't remember if it does)